# angular material 2 paginator with mat-table initialization

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, angular5

I'm trying to make the angular material 2 paginator component work with the table component (mat-table directive).

I followed the mat-table documentation to add a paginator, trying to make their example work with my existing working mat table.

In the component.html I have a working mat table, and a paginator:

```
<div class="example-container">
    <mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
    // columns and rows
    </mat-table>
    <mat-paginator #paginator
                   [pageSize]="10"
                   [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]"
                   [showFirstLastButtons]="true">
    </mat-paginator>
</div>
```

The component that uses this html implements ngOnInit:

```
ngOnInit() {
    myapi.apirequest()
          .subscribe((dataResponse: any) => {
            this.dataSource = new BasicDataSource(dataResponse);
            this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
            console.log(this.paginator);
          });
      });
  }
```

And the component gets the paginator using @ViewChild:

```
@ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
```

---

The issue is the paginator does nothing and the next and previous buttons are greyed out.

> The console.log(this.paginator) gives :
>
> _changeDetectorRef: Object { _view: {…}, _viewContainerRef: null, _appRef: null } ​
>   _displayedPageSizeOptions: Array(3) [ 5, 10, 20 ] ​
>   _hidePageSize: false ​
>   _initialized: true ​
>   _intl: Object { itemsPerPageLabel: "Items per page:", nextPageLabel: "Next page", previousPageLabel: "Previous page", … } ​
>   _intlChanges: Object { closed: false, syncErrorThrown: false, syncErrorThrowable: false, … } ​
>   _length: 0 ​
>   _pageIndex: 0 ​
>   _pageSize: 10 ​
>   _pageSizeOptions: Array(3) [ 5, 10, 20 ] ​
>   _showFirstLastButtons: true ​ page: Object { _isScalar: false, closed: false, isStopped: false, … } ​
>   **proto**: Object { pageIndex: Getter & Setter, length: Getter & Setter, pageSize: Getter & Setter, … }

I don't know how to debug / understand what causes the paginator not to work.

My BasicDataSource extends DataSource and using ngAfterViewInit doest work because this.datasource is undefined at this point (api call not done).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Initialize paginator after view init.

```
 ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
  }
```

Initialize datasource with blank array.

```
ngOnInit() {
            this.dataSource = new BasicDataSource([]);
    myapi.apirequest()
          .subscribe((dataResponse: any) => {
            this.dataSource = new BasicDataSource(dataResponse);
            this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
            console.log(this.paginator);
          });
      });
  }
```