# Angular Material Table TypeError: Cannot read property 'cars' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, ngoninit, angular-material-table

I am having a problem with Angular Material Table ([Angular Material Table](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview))

I ran `ng generate @angular/material:material-table --name=car-table` to generate the default angular table, which works fine. 
But if I try to inject the data (cars) to the `CarsTableDataSource` it stops working. It must be something related with async functions and `ngOnInit` lifecycle hooks.

You can see the code in [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-wmxs4k). The critical part is in the `src/app/cars/` folder.

**cars.component.ts**

```ts
import {Component, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {Car} from '../car';
import {CarService} from '../car.service';
import {MatPaginator, MatSort, MatTable} from '@angular/material';
import {CarsTableDataSource} from './cars-table-datasource';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-cars',
  templateUrl: './cars.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cars.component.css']
})
export class CarsComponent implements OnInit {
  cars: Car[];

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
  @ViewChild(MatTable) table: MatTable<Car>;
  dataSource: CarsTableDataSource;

  /** Columns displayed in the table. Columns IDs can be added, removed, or reordered. */
  displayedColumns = ['id', 'name', 'img_url'];

  constructor(private carService: CarService) {
  }

  async ngOnInit() {
    console.log('before getting cars: ');
    console.log(this.cars);
    this.cars = await this.carService.getCars().toPromise();
    console.log('got cars:');
    console.log(this.cars);
    this.dataSource = new CarsTableDataSource(this.paginator, this.sort, this.cars);
  }

  add(name: string) {
    name = name.trim();
    if (!name) {
      return;
    }
    this.carService.addCar({name} as Car)
      .subscribe(car => {
        this.cars = [...this.cars, car];
        console.log(this.cars);
        console.log('rendering rows');
        this.table.renderRows();
      });
  }

  delete(car: Car) {
    this.cars = this.cars.filter(c => c !== car);
    this.carService.deleteCar(car).subscribe();
    this.table.renderRows();
  }
}
```

**cars-table-datasource.ts**

```ts
import {DataSource} from '@angular/cdk/collections';
import {MatPaginator, MatSort} from '@angular/material';
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';
import {merge, Observable, of as observableOf} from 'rxjs';
import {Car} from '../car';

/**
 * Data source for the CarsTable view. This class should
 * encapsulate all logic for fetching and manipulating the displayed cars
 * (including sorting, pagination, and filtering).
 */
export class CarsTableDataSource extends DataSource<CarsTableItem> {
  // cars: CarsTableItem[];

  constructor(private paginator: MatPaginator, private sort: MatSort, public cars: Car[]) {
    super();
  }

  /**
   * Connect this cars source to the table. The table will only update when
   * the returned stream emits new items.
   * @returns A stream of the items to be rendered.
   */
  connect(): Observable<CarsTableItem[]> {
    // Combine everything that affects the rendered cars into one update
    // stream for the cars-table to consume.
    const dataMutations = [
      observableOf(this.cars),
      this.paginator.page,
      this.sort.sortChange
    ];

    // Set the paginator's length
    this.paginator.length = this.cars.length;

    return merge(...dataMutations).pipe(map(() => {
      return this.getPagedData(this.getSortedData([...this.cars]));
    }));
  }

  /**
   *  Called when the table is being destroyed. Use this function, to clean up
   * any open connections or free any held resources that were set up during connect.
   */
  disconnect() {
  }

  /**
   * Paginate the cars (client-side). If you're using server-side pagination,
   * this would be replaced by requesting the appropriate cars from the server.
   */
  private getPagedData(data: CarsTableItem[]) {
    const startIndex = this.paginator.pageIndex * this.paginator.pageSize;
    return data.splice(startIndex, this.paginator.pageSize);
  }

  /**
   * Sort the cars (client-side). If you're using server-side sorting,
   * this would be replaced by requesting the appropriate cars from the server.
   */
  private getSortedData(data: CarsTableItem[]) {
    if (!this.sort.active || this.sort.direction === '') {
      return data;
    }

    return data.sort((a, b) => {
      const isAsc = this.sort.direction === 'asc';
      switch (this.sort.active) {
        case 'name':
          return compare(a.name, b.name, isAsc);
        case 'id':
          return compare(+a.id, +b.id, isAsc);
        default:
          return 0;
      }
    });
  }
}

/** Simple sort comparator for example ID/Name columns (for client-side sorting). */
function compare(a, b, isAsc) {
  return (a < b ? -1 : 1) * (isAsc ? 1 : -1);
}
```

**cars.component.html**

```html
<div>
  <label>Car name:
    <input #carName />
  </label>
  <!-- (click) passes input value to add() and then clears the input -->
  <button (click)="add(carName.value); carName.value=''">
    add
  </button>
</div>

<h2>My Cars</h2>
<div class="mat-elevation-z8 centered-table-div">
  <table mat-table class="full-width-table" [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort aria-label="Elements">

    <!-- Image Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="img_url">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Image</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
        <img [src]="row.img_url" alt="car image" class="car-image"/>
      </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Id Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Id</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.id}}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Name Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Name</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.name}}</td>
    </ng-container>


    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
  </table>

  <mat-paginator #paginator
                 [length]="dataSource.cars.length"
                 [pageIndex]="0"
                 [pageSize]="5"
                 [pageSizeOptions]="[3, 5, 25, 50]">
  </mat-paginator>
</div>
```

The problem resides in the `ngOnInit` and

```html
  <mat-paginator #paginator
                 [length]="dataSource.cars.length"
                 [pageIndex]="0"
                 [pageSize]="5"
                 [pageSizeOptions]="[3, 5, 25, 50]">
  </mat-paginator>
```

As an error I get `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'cars' of undefined`, which means that `dataSource` is undefined when parsing the template, but the function `ngOnInit`:

```ts
  async ngOnInit() {
    console.log('before getting cars: ');
    console.log(this.cars);
    this.cars = await this.carService.getCars().toPromise();
    console.log('got cars:');
    console.log(this.cars);
    this.dataSource = new CarsTableDataSource(this.paginator, this.sort, this.cars);
  }
```

prints out:

[image]
[image]

The page still loads everything, but I can't for example add cars through the method, because they do add in the database, but don't update in the view despite calling `this.table.renderRows()` as mentioned in the documentation:

> Since the table optimizes for performance, it will not automatically check for changes to the data array. Instead, when objects are added, removed, or moved on the data array, you can trigger an update to the table's rendered rows by calling its `renderRows()` method.

I tried making the `ngOnInit` use `Observable`s instead of `async/await`, but it didn't work either:

```ts
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('before getting cars: ');
    console.log(this.cars);
    this.carService.getCars().subscribe(cars => {
      this.cars = cars;
      console.log('got cars:');
      console.log(this.cars);
      this.dataSource = new CarsTableDataSource(this.paginator, this.sort, this.cars);
    });
  }
```

If I don't do any of the database fetching stuff in the `ngOnInit`, then there aren't any errors.

I also cannot add any cars with the `add()` right now as was aforementioned.

If you need any other information - feel free to ask me and I will make sure to answer as soon as I can.

**Edit**

If I edit the code to look like this:

```ts
async ngOnInit() {
  console.log('before getting cars: ');
  console.log(this.cars);
  console.log('got cars:');
  this.cars = await this.carService.getCars().toPromise();
  console.log(this.cars);
  this.dataSource = new CarsTableDataSource(this.paginator, this.sort, this.cars);
}
```

The order of the errors changes to:

[image]
[image]

which means that the error happens in the

```ts
this.cars = await this.carService.getCars().toPromise();
```

I've already tried it with a `.subscribe()` and doing everything in that block, but no luck there.

**Edit 2**

As stated in [here (stackoverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50022662/angular-material-2-paginator-with-mat-table-initialization?rq=1) you have to initialize the `dataSource` with a blank object, because the view is parsed before all the microtasks in `ngOnInit` finish.
Initialize paginator after view init.

```
  async ngOnInit() {
    this.dataSource = new CarsTableDataSource(this.paginator, this.sort, []);
    console.log('before getting cars: ');
    console.log(this.cars);
    this.cars = await this.carService.getCars().toPromise();
    console.log('got cars:');
    console.log(this.cars);
    this.dataSource = new CarsTableDataSource(this.paginator, this.sort, this.cars);
  }
```

Now it works, but this is sort of a hack. I don't know why, but whenever where is asyc code in a lifecycle hook in Angular, the hook finishes before the async code has finished. I don't know why. 
After it sees `await` it immediately exits the function and only after that does the `dataSource` get initialized. I would really appreciate an explanation.

**Edit 3**

Another workaround is adding the null-conditional operator in the view where it breaks like so:

```html
  <mat-paginator #paginator
                 [length]="dataSource?.cars.length"
                 [pageIndex]="0"
                 [pageSize]="5"
                 [pageSizeOptions]="[3, 5, 25, 50]">
  </mat-paginator>
```

With this line:

```
[length]="dataSource?.cars.length"
```

As the view is executed when ngOnInit is half-finished, you have to add this everywhere you use that property, so that it doesn't get in the final html when the view is parsed.

**Edit 4**

I updated the link to the Stackblitz app, it is now as minimalistic as possible to represent the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Create the `cars` object before the `constructor`. Angular doesn't know that property when run the application.

```
cars: Car[] = [new Car()]

constructor () { }
```

This is just to tell angular that template will contain an array of cars type. **(1)**

**Edited**

In `CarsTableDataSource` do the same as above.

cars: Car[] = [new Car()]

and remove them from the constructor. **(1)**

Another solution is, making `CarsTableDataSource` an @Injectable so to delegate the DI to Angular.

```
...
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class CarsTableDataSource extends DataSource<CarsTableItem> {

constructor ( private paginator: MatPaginator, private sort: MatSort, public cars: Car[] )

...

}
```

**(1)** P.D.: This is just for quick fix, i'll try to find out a more elegant, way to do it, cause i've deal with such issue before, and that patch works, but doesn't see that follow OOP.

Comment: I tried this. It doesn't change anything since the `ngOnInit` initializes `this.cars` from the database, before the view is rendered.

Comment: Merry Christmas to you too. Your solution doesn't work, since the `dataSource` is undefined, not the `cars`, I could try to initialize the `dataSource` with dummy data so that it's not undefined, but that's not the point. You may try opening the Stackblitz link I shared, which has the code and a window with the running app on the right side, and see if you can do something there.

Comment: I've edited my answer. You only need to tell angular that `cars` object is here (initialized), no need to add dummy data, it's unnecesary (unless you want it, for test the visual design).

Comment: Why would I delegate this to angular? `@Injectable` means that Angular should call the constructor, create a singleton and then inject it wherever I have it for DI. Have you tried if this works? Your solution makes Angular throw `StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[MatPaginator]`, because it doesn't know with what to fill the constructor arguments.

Answer (score 1):

The connect() method is returning an `Observable<CarsTableItem[]>`. And as `getPagedData` and `getSortedData` are not returning Observable, the undefined due to delay is occured when initializing the `CarsTableDataSource` and Material Table.

Try to add `.asObservable()` or something else to these methods.

As a best practice, you should inject `CarsService` in the implementation of `CarsTableDataSource` and let it dealing with data loading and pagination stuff.

Comment: The error states that there is no `dataSource` at that moment (`undefined`). I edited my question. In the `connect()` the `dataMutations` array has an `Observable` and 2 `EventEmitter`s, so it kind of is an array of `Observables`. Then I think that when it merges the `Observable`s, the `pipe` subscribes and changes every value to the array of cars. Am I right?

Comment: I edited my question, you may see what I discovered.